# Column splitter line is Invisible in Infragistics XamWebGrid

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, datagrid, infragistics

I am using a Infragistics XamWebGrid, in which the column's of type TextColumn are created dynamically and added to it. But sometimes, the splitter line in between the columns are not getting displayed. I couldn't able to reproduce this scenario everytime. Is it a problem with the Infragistics control? Or what else may cause this issue?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce the issue in a sample, you should submit it to Infragistics support so that they can evaluate if it is an issue with the control.  You can contact support either through the forums or by submitting a case from the [get help page](http://www.infragistics.com/support/get-help.aspx).

I did attempt to reproduce the issue with a current version of the XamGrid and wasn't able to.  Note that the XamWebGrid was renamed to XamGrid in NetAdvantage for Silverlight 2010 Volume 2.  There are more details in the Infragistics blogs:
http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/devin_rader/archive/2010/06/15/xaml-control-unification-changes-in-2010-2.aspx